# Searching a list of strings within a column of data

Tags: python, string, pandas, lambda

I have a column of data that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

   Items
0  Product A + Product B + Product C   
1  Product A + Product B + Product B1 + Product C1 
2
```

I would like to look through the items and find out if the column contains a few specific items, relating to products I am interested in flagging as containing within the items column :

```
My_Items = ['Product B', 'Product C', 'Product C1']
```

I've tried the following lambda function but it is not picking up the strings i'm searching if there is more than 1 product within the column:

```
df['My Items'] = df['Items'].apply(lambda x: 'Contains my items' if x in My_Items else '')
```

Does anyone know how can search for multiple strings in a list within a lambda function?

Thank you for any help or suggestions.

Kind regards

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you guys! The solution I was looking for ended up being a combination of both of your answers!

What I ended up doing was this for the mask, so I could filter:

```
DF['My_Items'] = DF.Items.str.findall('|'.join(My_list)).str.len().gt(1)
```

Then this for the list of items, so I can now analyse the combinations:

```
DF['My_Items'] = DF.Items.str.findall('|'.join(My_list)).astype(str)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) for count matched values and then tested with [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for greater like `1`:

```
mask = df.Items.str.count('|'.join(My_Items)).gt(1)

df['My Items'] = np.where(mask,'Contains 2 or more items', '')
print (df)
                                             Items                  My Items
0                Product A + Product B + Product C  Contains 2 or more items
1  Product A + Product B + Product B1 + Product C1  Contains 2 or more items
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.Items.str.count('|'.join(My_Items)))
0    2
1    3
Name: Items, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you may use [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and check we get at least `2` matches:

```
import numpy as np

m = df.Items.str.findall('|'.join(My_Items)).str.len().ge(2)
df['My items'] = np.where(m, 'Contains at least 2 items', '')
```

---

If we check with an additional row containing only `1` of the products:

```
print(df)

                        Items  \
0                Product A + Product B + Product C      
1  Product A + Product B + Product B1 + Product C1     
2                            Product A + Product D    

                    My items  
0  Contains at least 2 items  
1  Contains at least 2 items  
2
```

Where `df.Items.str.findall('|'.join(My_Items))` is giving you a list with all found matches:

```
df.Items.str.findall('|'.join(My_Items))

 [Product B, Product C]
1    [Product B, Product B, Product C]
2                                   []
Name: Items, dtype: object
```